# What technology to use to avoid too many VMs

Tags: performance, web-applications, architecture, google-cloud-platform

I have a small web and mobile application partly running on a webserver written in PHP (Symfony). I have a few clients using the application, and slowly expanding to more clients.

My back-end architecture looks like this at the moment:

- Database is Cloud SQL running on GCP (every client has it's own
  database instance)
- Files are stored on Cloud Storage (GCP) or S3 (AWS), depending on the client. (every client has it's own bucket)
- PHP application is running in a Compute Engine VM (GCP), (every client has it's own VM)

Now the thing is, in the PHP code, the only thing client specific is a settings file with the database credentials and the Storage/S3 keys in it. All the other code is exactly the same for every client. And mostly the different VMs sit idle all day, waiting on a few hours usage per client.

I'm trying to find a way to avoid having to create and maintain a VM for every customer. How could I rearchitect my back-end so I can keep separate Databases and Storage Buckets per client, but only scale up my VM's when capacity is needed?

I'm hearing alot about Docker, was thinking about keeping db credentials and keys in a Redis DB or Cloud Datastore, was looking at Heroku, AppEngine, Elastic Beanstalk, ...

This is my ideal scenario as I see it now

1. An incoming request is done, hits a load balancer
2. From the request, determine which client the request is for
3. Find the correct settings file, or credentials from a DB
4. Inject the settings file in an unused "container"
5. Handle the request
6. Make the container idle again

And somewhere in there, determine based on the the amount of incoming requests or traffic, if I need to spin up or spin down containers to handle the extra or reduced (temporary) load.

All this information overload has me stuck, I have no idea what direction to choose, and I fail seeing how implementing any of the above technologies will actually fix my problem.

Comment: Can't you simply give each client their own sub domain? When the application gets requested you chose which settings file to use depending on sub domain.

Comment: different domain is also support on one vm

Comment: I added my "ideal scenario" to my question, to give a little more information.

Comment: Does every customer need their own VM if the code is the same?  If your load balancer can identify the client, it should be able to pass that information along to whichever instance is tasked with dealing with the request.  Could the file containing client details sit on every server (assuming that it will be secured), and retrieve the appropriate client's details on a per-request basis?  In other words, can you allow any server to handle any request?  As for scaling, maybe Kubernetes can help (if you go the Docker route) - http://kubernetes.io/.

Comment: Every customer does not need their own VM, that part is a huge overkill at the moment. In theory I could place the settings file on every server, the clients do not have access to the servers.

Comment: I would strongly consider going that route.  Overall, it should be a simpler architecture.  It should make fault tolerance much easier as well - if a server goes down, it doesn't mean that the application is out of action for any particular client - any other server can play the part just as well.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Any idea how a load balancer can identify clients? My PHP backend is simple oauth login with calls to the API containing Bearer tokens for authorization. At the moment every client has a different domain.

Comment: I'm not sure which load balancer you're using, but if it's something like HAProxy, you can get your clients to connect via SSL and then use the details within their certs to identify them.  Something like this:  http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/06/13/ssl-client-certificate-information-in-http-headers-and-logs/

Comment: If you wanted to go down the route of utilising Docker then I would say look at GKE (Google Container Engine) as it runs on Kubernetes. Kubernetes can handle all your configuration and keys via secrets so they are injected dynamically into your containers/applications. It will also handle your load balancing, request mapping and container utilisation - if you want any more help with this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways do it with minimum efforts:

- Rewrite loading of config file depending from customer
- Make several back-end web sites on one VM (best choice i think)

Comment: I added some extra information to my question. Thing is that your solution works as long as my VM can take the load. What happens when I get too many clients, and the VM gets crowded? Create a new VM, and split my clients over 2 VM's? What if 1 of those VMs has very high traffic, and the other has none?

Comment: If you will realize you scenario you will be need to make cross VM session storage. If you have this processing model - so all ok, other way you will rewrite all session depended code.

Comment: And about you question. Of cause this situation not optimal from point of view of resource using, but high level of optimization require more complex system and will give more complex problems. So KISS.

Comment: To address the load concerns you could include GCE features like [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) and [URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/url-map) in your architecture. To autoscale you would need to make the VMs stateless (As explained in the video databases, in that case, cannot live in the VMs).